# Shared in-memory database for client activity processing

Tags: database, spring-boot, redis, in-memory-database

Currently I am realising that I come to the limits of relational databases. Having n>>1000 clients periodically (each 10 seconds) requesting a simple microservice endpoint (signals its activity), I just have to make a decision if a client is active or not (3 periods of requests missing).

The naive approach would be to make a database update for each clients request (which has bad performance impacts and hence would not be a suitable solution).
Now, having more instances of those services (for future service scaling), any bulk processing (e.g. by using a periodically processed queue structure) would automatically introduce database locking issues due to subsequent requests of the same clients by different instances (this client id would be part of multiple database bulk updates by different services). Hence, those updates would partially fail even for clients not beeing processed in parallel.

Is there any way to make this processing reliable and high-performant using other (e.g. in-memory) database solutions like Redis or somehing else? In Redis I don't get the trick to manage keys and values in a way to retrieve all keys that were not changed during the last x periods.

Do you have any ideas about well-established technologies to cope with that issue?

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: Sorry, I should not write a question using a mobile phone next time. At the end I managed finalizing my question.

Comment: This may help https://github.com/petreboy14/redis-scheduler

Comment: TTL in redis doesn't work reliably